# Overloaded typecasts don't work

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, typecast-operator

I've built a little class representing a decimal number, called Complex. 
I want to be able to cast it to double, so here's my code

Complex.h

```
public:
    operator double();
```

Complext.cpp

```
Complex::operator double()
{
return _num;
}
```

_num is a field of type double of course

That seems to be okay. The problem is in another class where I actually try to cast a 
complex object into double. That's my function:

```
const RegMatrix& RegMatrix::operator *= (double num)
{
    Complex factor(num);
    for(int i=0; i<_numRow; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<_numCol; j++)
        {
            Complex temp = _matrix[i][j];
            _matrix[i][j] = (double) (temp * factor); //<---ERROR HERE
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

That results in `invalid cast from type ‘const Complex’ to type ‘double’`

I have no clue why it happens. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `operator double` a `const` function:

```
operator double() const;
```

and

```
Complex::operator double() const {
    return _num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly states, the is no conversion to double for a ***const*** Complex. Simply define your conversion operator like this:

```
operator double() const;

Complex::operator double() const
{
    return _num;
}
```

Note the const modifier at the end. You should really look for information on const-correctness in C++.